# Why the compiler is complaining here when apparently there is no error?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

Whenever I try to compile the following program, I get this message from the compiler (g++ 4.4.3). Any idea, why?

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:52: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

Line 52 has the code **rc = pthread_create_with_stack( &thread[t], BusyWork, t );**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 4

void *stackAddr[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_t thread[NUM_THREADS];
pthread_attr_t attr;

void *BusyWork(void *t)
{
   int i;
   long tid;
   double result=0.0;
       tid = (long)t;
   printf("Thread %ld starting...\n",tid);
   for ( i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
   {
      result = result + sin(i*tid) * tan(i*tid);
   }
   printf("Thread %ld done. Result = %e\n", tid, result);
   pthread_exit((void*) t);
}

void pthread_create_with_stack( pthread_t * pthread, void *(*start_routine) (void *), int tid )
{
    const size_t STACKSIZE = 0xC00000; //12582912
    int rc;
    size_t i;
    pid_t pid;

    stackAddr[tid] = malloc(STACKSIZE);
    pthread_attr_setstack(&attr, stackAddr[tid], STACKSIZE);

    rc = pthread_create( pthread, &attr, start_routine, (void*)0 );
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int rc;
   long t;
   void *status;

   /* Initialize and set thread detached attribute */
   pthread_attr_init(&attr);
   pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
   {
      printf("Main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
      // The following line is the line 52, where error occurs
      rc = pthread_create_with_stack( &thread[t], BusyWork, t ); 
      if (rc) 
      {
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
   }

   /* Free attribute and wait for the other threads */
   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
   for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) 
   {
      rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
      if (rc) 
      {
         printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_join() is %d\n", rc);
         exit(-1);
      }
      printf("Main: completed join with thread %ld having a status"   
            "of %ld\n",t,(long)status);
    }

    printf("Main: program completed. Exiting.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Why is there "apparently no error" when in fact you apparently made a mistake? It's always good to suspect your own code first rather than starting with the assumption that "my code is fine, why is the compiler behaving oddly?"

Answer (score 10):

`pthread_create_with_stack` returns `void`, yet you're trying to save this `void` "value" in an `int`, which is an error.

Comment: To be fair, the compiler warning actually got pretty close to describing the situation...

Answer (score 5):

It's this line

```
rc = pthread_create_with_stack( &thread[t], BusyWork, t );
```

Your definition of pthread_create_with_stack is of type void. Should be of type void* and return rc, the result of pthread_create().

Since pthread_create_with_stack is a void function, and it returns nothing in the definition, setting rc to its return value is not only meaningless, it's an error gcc/g++ won't even let you try to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an error.  A return type of `void` means that the function returns no value.  You're trying to assign the return value of `pthread_create_with_stack` to a local variable, but there is no return value to assign.

You should instead declare `pthread_create_with-stack` as returning an `int`, and then make it actually return a value:

```
int pthread_create_with-stack(...)
{
    ...
    return pthread_create(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the return value from a `void` function and trying to assign it to a variable. `pthread_create_with_stack` doesn't return anything; don't assign it or use it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `pthread_create_with_stack` is a `void` function. It doesn't return a value. You can't assign it's result to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

pthread_create_with_stack is defined as returning void.

```
 rc = pthread_create_with_stack( &thread[t], BusyWork, t );
```

where rc is defined as int is not legal

Answer (score 0):

void simply means "nothing"
N you simply cant save "nothing"!